# Drywall extended out from studs?

Tags: drywall, basement, studs

I moved into a house I’m renting a few months back. I’m allowed to drill holes in the walls so long as I cover them before I move out...

So I’ve marked the studs, I drill, and there’s nothing behind the drywall. I’m no expert, but I’m a little confused as to how I’ve found a stud and there’s no stud. Could the drywall be extended?

In case you’re thinking I’m stupid (though I’m not saying I’m not! Haha), here’s a little more explaination of what I’ve done:

- Found stud with Franklin Sensors Prosensor 710
- Confirmed by sound (knocking on wall) after drilling and not finding a stud
- Confirmed with magnetic stud finder
- Still confused, used a piece of wire to check depth - there’s something in the way of the wire 4 and 1/4 inch deep, nothing in the way left or right of where the stud apparently is.

I don’t want to go cutting huge holes in the wall to figure out what’s behind them unless I have to. Could the drywall be extended out for some reason? These are the walls around the foundation of the basement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply put...you missed the stud location when you made the hole.

You could try using a wire in the wall up, down, right and left from your hole to locate the actual stud location.

Note that stud locators and never deterministic for every situation.

Comment: Well, I've checked in 3 places and each time drilled 3 holes 2 inches apart horizontally. Checking the depth with the wire, the stud location as found with the 3 methods (electric stud finder, magnetic stud finder, and by sound)  is always 4 1/4" deep. Left and right of the stud is 6+" . So to simply say I missed the stud, I'm not convinced.

Comment: Maybe this will convince: the drywall is attached to something, somewhere ;-)